# Is there details on using Azure FHIR API / Azure FHIR Open Source with a service bus?

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I have been tasked with finding out if/how the Azure FHIR API or the Azure FHIR Open Source can be used in conjunction with an enterprise service bus? however I have found little to no information about these two together?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve @eaw1234?

Answer (score 0):

Below template helps to deploy ***Microsoft Open Source FHIR*** Server , can be found in the below URL.

> https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/DefaultDeployment.md

This process creates the instances Cosmos DB, Azure Web App, and source code using an Azure Resource Manager template.

To integrate the Azure FHIR with service bus, we can quickly integrate a FHIR server into our own application using the above template and Azure enables to quickly ingest and manage FHIR datasets in the cloud to track and manage data.